# newbie about npm, how to use local project other than going online

Tags: npm

I am very new to npm, so possibly very easy, but just can't figure out.

I downloaded a open source project(say it is RailWrapper), which has a dependency to another open source project:

```
"dependencies":
{
    rail-fares: "^1.55"
}
```

rail-fares is another open source nodejs project I can download. What I want is to download the source code of rail-fares project, make some changes locally and play bit.

How can I tell the project(RailWrapper) to use my local build project, another than from the offical place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose two approaches:

1. Get the library, play around and require it in your project code with this:
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-module

or

2. calling: `npm install --save "C:\path\to\module"`
   or 
   Including this in your package.json:

   "dependencies": {
           "rail-fares": "file:///C:\path\to\module" 
        },

Then calling `npm install`
Note: try with and without C:\ in the path above.

note this only copies the package to your node_modules folder but doesn't do a proper linking for further dev. 
You can see details here: 
https://jaketrent.com/post/npm-install-local-files/
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12027